# Regarding foreach loop and arraylist

Tags: c#, foreach, arraylist

```
ArrayList demo = new ArrayList();
demo.Add(tbxProjName.Text);
string DatabaseFieldValues;
foreach (string dataType in demo)
          {
             DatabaseFieldValues = dataType + ",";
              Response.Write(DatabaseFieldValues);

             Session["DatabaseFieldValuesSession"] = DatabaseFieldValues; 
          } 
Response.Write(Session["DatabaseFieldValuesSession"]);
```

In this code,

In foreach loop I am able to print all the items of arraylist and i am storing that string in session, but when I am printing thae session value it only prints the last item of the arraylist.

How can I store all the items of the arraylist in a session?

Comment: As an aside, consider using List<T> which gives a strongly typed collection,  rather than an ArrayList which is pretty much deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below:

```
ArrayList demo = new ArrayList();
demo.Add(tbxProjName.Text);
string DatabaseFieldValues;
foreach (string dataType in demo)
          {
             DatabaseFieldValues += dataType + ",";
              Response.Write(DatabaseFieldValues);
          } 

Session["DatabaseFieldValuesSession"] = DatabaseFieldValues; 
Response.Write(Session["DatabaseFieldValuesSession"]);
```

Instead of DatabaseFieldValues = dataType + ","; you should use DatabaseFieldValues += dataType + ",";

This is important because you want to add the datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Your overwriting your session value each loop through to the last item because your mishandling the string concact.

You have to remember that strings are immutable - when you change it by adding on a new string to the end, the result is a new string, not a modification of the original. That's why the += change works, it stores the new string result of the concatenation into the original string.

```
ArrayList demo = new ArrayList();
demo.Add(tbxProjName.Text);
string DatabaseFieldValues;
foreach (string dataType in demo)
{
    DatabaseFieldValues += dataType + ",";
    Response.Write(DatabaseFieldValues);
} 
Session["DatabaseFieldValuesSession"] = DatabaseFieldValues; 
Response.Write(Session["DatabaseFieldValuesSession"]);
```

Also I would suggest moving away from `ArrayList` into a strongly typed collection

```
IList<string> demo = new List<string>();
demo.Add(tbxProjName.Text);

Session["DatabaseFieldValuesSession"] = string.Join(",",demo);

Response.Write(Session["DatabaseFieldValuesSession"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the last value every time you do

```
Session["DatabaseFieldValuesSession"] = DatabaseFieldValues;
```

Consider doing something like

```
 Session["DatabaseFieldValuesSession"] += DatabaseFieldValues;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or alternative to `+=` look into using [`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: This is a complete non-sequitor.

Comment: With regards to the context of the OP, explain how it is a non-sequitor.

Comment: You can't yield return inside the context of a method, and it doesn't actually explain or solve the problem. I didn't down vote or anything, it is something good to learn about.